# Approach for function placement (inside/outside parent)

Tags: javascript

### Exhibit A

A simple function for generating random points around a rectangle

```
function makeRectanglePointB(box, index){

    /* the `getPoint` function relies on `box` from current scope */
    function getPoint(my_index) {
        switch (my_index) {
            case 0: return new Point(box.p1.x, box.p2.y);
            case 1: return box.p2;
            case 2: return new Point(box.p2.x, box.p1.y);
            case 3: return box.p1;
        }
    }

    var line = new Vector(getPoint(index), getPoint((index + 1) % 4));
    return new Point(randomPoint(line.p1.x, line.p2.x), randomPoint(line.p1.y, line.p2.y));

}
```

### Exhibit B

... perhaps make `getPoint` function operate only on passed arguments ...

```
function makeRectanglePointB(box, index){

    /* keep the `getPoint` function inside the scope where it is used */
    function getPoint(my_box, my_index) {
        switch (my_index) {
            case 0: return new Point(my_box.p1.x, my_box.p2.y);
            case 1: return my_box.p2;
            case 2: return new Point(my_box.p2.x, my_box.p1.y);
            case 3: return my_box.p1;
        }
    }

    var line = new Vector(getPoint(box, index), getPoint(box, (index + 1) % 4));
    return new Point(randomPoint(line.p1.x, line.p2.x), randomPoint(line.p1.y, line.p2.y));

}

/* the `getPoint` function is not accessible here... */
```

### Exhibit C

... or move the `getPoint` function to outer scope ...

```
function getPoint(my_box, my_index) {
    switch (my_index) {
        case 0: return new Point(my_box.p1.x, my_box.p2.y);
        case 1: return my_box.p2;
        case 2: return new Point(my_box.p2.x, my_box.p1.y);
        case 3: return my_box.p1;
    }
}

function makeRectanglePointB(box, index){

    var line = new Vector(getPoint(box, index), getPoint(box, (index + 1) % 4));
    return new Point(randomPoint(line.p1.x, line.p2.x), randomPoint(line.p1.y, line.p2.y));

}

/* now the `getPoint` function is accessible here... */
```

### Question

I like explicitly passing arguments, as it makes it easier to test, as it requires less context to run. I also like moving it to outer scope, so it is explicit that it does not rely on any variables in it's surrounding context, but I don't really like it being generally available to be called from outer scope.

What is the best way to organise the `getPoint` function?

Comment: what are you optimizing for?

Comment: This is almost entirely stylistic. If there are performance differences, they'll be minor. So do whatever you find best for your purposes.

Comment: Google's recommendations: [Optimizing JavaScript code: Avoiding pitfalls with closures](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exhibits A and C are both fine. B doesn't make much sense, if `my_box == box` all the time you don't need an extra parameter and can rely on closure.

If the function relies on lots of scope variables, or is logically completely linked to that single function, a local function is the way to go. The implementation of `makeRectanglePointB` might change at any time, and would include the `getPoint` as an internal subroutine.

If the function might be used at different places, or needs to be exposed for some reasons (testability for white-box testing), then you'd go with a separate function. You would not make it part of the public API though, but document it as internal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor:

```
var MakeRectanglePointB;
(function(){
function PointB(index, MakeBContext){
  this.parent = MakeBContext;
  this.index = index || MakeBContext.index;
  var b = MakeBContext.box;
  this.get = function(){
    switch(this.index){
      case 0:
        return new Point(b.p1.x, b.p2.y);
      case 1:
        return b.p2;
      case 2:
        return new Point(b.p2.x, b.p1.y);
      case 3:
        return b.p1;
    }
  }
  this.someOtherMethod = function(){
    // code here
    return this; // this access
  }
  this.getMakeRectB = function(){
    // code here
    return MakeBContext; // access to another this
  }
}
MakeRectanglePointB = function(box, index){
  this.box = box; this.index = index;
  this.point = function(idx){
    return new PointB(idx, this);
  }
  this.anotherFunc = function(){
    return 'Well, now.';
  }
}
})();
var mb = new MakeRectanglePointB(box_var, index_var); // replace box_var and index_var
var pb = mb.point();
var line = new Vector(mb.point().get(), mb.point((mb.index + 1) % 4)).get());
console.log(mb.point().someOtherMethod().getMakeRectB().anotherFunc());
```

Comment: This is interesting... can you explain what some of the benefits of this pattern are?

Comment: Since I'm returning another constructor, it could have it's own properties. It takes an initial index that can be changed. You could use this kind of structure to return a new instance of a constructor that only has access to itself, if you want. Each Object can have it's own `this`.

Comment: And how is that better or simpler than what the OP already has?